# How to make background color of div tag keep changing using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change background of div tag continuously using for loop and rgb() values .
following is my code written in sample.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>sample</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script >
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var r=0;
            var g=0;    
            var b=0;

            for(r=0;r<255;r++)
            {
                for(g=0;g<255;g++)
                {
                    for(b=0;b<255;b++)
                    {
                        $("#sqr").css("background-color","rgb(r,g,b)");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        </script>


        <style>
        #sqr{background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
             height:200px;
              width:200px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="sqr">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

so can enyone tell me how should i make a code so that  background color of div keeps changing automatically when page is loaded ?
Note that i want to change color very smoothly.

If you want to  see how effects i want then visit:[here](http://www.designweekportland.com/) and see effects its showing.

As per some suggestions I have changed my code to:

```
$("#sqr").css("background-color","rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")");
```

Now it is taking values of rgb correctly ,but not loading  effects correctly in browser,shows me dialog box:

[image: Dialog Box]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As this question is tagged as CSS, I would like to contribute a pure CSS solution to this, simply use CSS3 `@keyframes` and you can simply add colors to the element you want, can step the animation using `%` and also, you can use `animation-iteration-count` and set it to `infinite`. If you want to iterate it for limited times, just changed the `infinite` to whatever value you desire but make sure it's an integer.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctCNG/)

```
.animate {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-animation: animate_bg 5s;
    animation: animate_bg 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes animate_bg {
    0%   {background:red;}
    50%  {background:green;}
    100% {background:blue;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg {
    0%   {background:red;}
    50%  {background:green;}
    100% {background:blue;}
}
```

This is introduced in CSS3 spec, so you can refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Browser_Compatibility) link for browser support.

---

There are many [polyfills](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=keyframe%20support%20css3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=wXFOUsb2OoiClAWk6oHADQ#q=keyframe%20support%20css3%20jquery&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) available for the browsers which are not supporting CSS3 `@keyframes`, so you may need to use this if you are looking to support older browsers, if you don't care about the old one's, than you can use this without any hesitation.

Comment: +1 Really amazing, does this supported only by latest browsers?

Comment: @user1671639 added support link :)

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems fine besides the code where you set the CSS.

Change the code :

```
$("#sqr").css("background-color","rgb(r,g,b)");
```

To :

```
$("#sqr").css("background-color","rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")");
```

This will now pass in the number values, i.e.

```
$("#sqr").css("background-color","rgb(254,254,254)");
```

Where as before it would have simply passed the values `r,g,b` because you placed them within a string.

Comment: Thank u so much , now it's taking values rgb but browser is not changing color smoothly and prompting a dialog box that "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete." So please can u suggest me any solution for that . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`.setInterval()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Enclose your code within a function called `animate`

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(animate, 500);
```

Not sure correct this

```
$("#sqr").css("background-color","rgb(" + r +"," +g+"," +b +")");
```