# How to change background color "continuously" without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is here any way to continuously change the background color like a rainbow?

Comment: Yes! but what i don't see is your trials? Do you have any to show? That would be nice to answer.

Comment: You could use a javascript interval timer to change the background color

Comment: did you tried something your self ? it will good provide your work in question to get better help

Comment: 5 second google search: https://codepen.io/nohoid/pen/kIfto

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175664/how-to-make-background-color-of-div-tag-keep-changing-using-jquery

Comment: Before 3 years someone tried his best and then asked question in SO got 3 answers, now with single line question there is almost 6 answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope you needed something like this.

```js
var body = $('body');
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'purple'];
var currentIndex = 0;
setInterval(function () {
   body.css({
     backgroundColor: colors[currentIndex]
   });
   if (!colors[currentIndex]) {
       currentIndex = 0;
   } else {
       currentIndex++;
   }
}, 100);
```

```css
body {
  transition: 200ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Epilepsy intensifies]

Comment: epilepsy warning!

Answer (score 6):

For colours, you may want to use [CSS animation](https://codepen.io/nohoid/pen/kIfto).

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>

.wrapper { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
background-size: 1800% 1800%;

-webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-z-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow { 
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
```

For changing between images, the code would be somewhat different:

```
<div class="topstrip" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></div>

    <script>
    var imagebackground = 0;
    var imgbackgrounds = [];
    imgbackgrounds[0] = '/images/image1.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[1] = '/images/image2.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[2] = '/images/image3.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[3] = '/images/image4.jpg';
    imgbackgrounds[4] = '/images/image5.jpg';


    function changeimage() {
        imagebackground++;
        if(imagebackground > 4) imagebackground = 0;

        $('.topstrip').fadeToggle("slow",function() {
            $('.topstrip').css({
                'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[imagebackground] + "')"
            });
            $('.topstrip').fadeToggle("slow");
        });


        setTimeout(changeimage, 5000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(changeimage, 5000);        
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I hope you mean a rainbow effect? This CSS code can provide it:

```
.wrapper { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
background-size: 1800% 1800%;

-webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-z-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow { 
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
```

Source: https://codepen.io/nohoid/pen/kIfto