# Changing color at specified intervals on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use some CSS and JavaScript on my web page.

I have 3 boxes and I want all 3 boxes to change to the different color and render to the screen and change color again.

For example,
I have 3 black boxes on the screen. When I click on a button
the program will wait for 2 seconds
then the 3 boxes will change to red. Wait for 2 seconds
then the 3 boxes will change to blue. Wait for 2 seconds
then the 3 boxes will change to green.

Here is what I have:

```js
elem1 = document.getElementById('1')
elem2 = document.getElementById('2')
elem3 = document.getElementById('3')
colorlist = ['purple', 'red', 'blue', 'green']

function changeColor() {
  showRed()
  //wait 2 seconds
  showBlue()
  //wait 2 seconds
  showGreen()
  //wait 2 seconds
}

function showRed() {
  elem1.style.background = "red"
  elem2.style.background = "blue"
  elem3.style.background = "green"
}

function showBlue() {
  elem1.style.background = "blue"
  elem2.style.background = "green"
  elem3.style.background = "red"
}

function showGreen() {
  elem1.style.background = "green"
  elem2.style.background = "red"
  elem3.style.background = "blue"
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column3 {
  float: left;
  min-width: 15px;
  max-width: 15px;
  min-height: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column3" id="1"></div>
  <div class="column3" id="2"></div>
  <div class="column3" id='3'></div>
  <button onclick='changeColor()'> Test </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make background color of div tag keep changing using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175664/how-to-make-background-color-of-div-tag-keep-changing-using-jquery)

Comment: What do you want, then? Why downvoted my answer? It works as you want.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer some else did. It wont show my vote because I have less than15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Use **loops**, if you do **same** **things** again.

Start and stop interval:

```
var interval;

function start() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {}, ms);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Go through a `NodeList` with

```
[].forEach.call()
```

**In total**

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes > div"),
  colors = ["blue", "green", "purple", "red"],
  ms = 2000,
  interval;

function start(els, colors, ms) {
  var i = 0;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    [].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    })
    i += 1;
    i === colors.length ? i = 0 : false;
  }, ms);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
  start(els, colors, ms);
})
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  stop();
});
```

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.boxes>div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: black;
}

button {
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox boxes">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="flexbox">
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
elem1 = document.getElementById('1')
elem2 = document.getElementById('2')
elem3 = document.getElementById('3')
colorlist = ['purple', 'red', 'blue', 'green']

function changeColor() {
 setInterval(function(){
  var c1=colorlist.length;
  var x=parseInt(Math.random()*c1);
  f(x);
 },2000);
/*  // Show updated color change for 2 seconds
  f(1)
  // Show updated color change for 2 seconds
  f(2)*/
}

function f(x) {
  elem1.style.background = colorlist[x]
  elem2.style.background = colorlist[x]
  elem3.style.background = colorlist[x]
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column3 {
  float: left;
  min-width: 15px;
  max-width: 15px;
  min-height: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column3" id="1"></div>
  <div class="column3" id="2"></div>
  <div class="column3" id='3'></div>
  <button onclick='changeColor()'> Test </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am wondering how I would do this if I need to call different methods so if there is three functions f1, f2, and f3 where each function does something different example f1(), //wait 2 seconds, f2(), //wait 2 seconds, f3()

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to execute a `function` at specified intervals. Please note, you have to clear your interval once you are done with the list, otherwise `setInterval` will keep executing the supplied `function`. You can do that by using [`clearInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

```js
elem1 = document.getElementById('1')
elem2 = document.getElementById('2')
elem3 = document.getElementById('3')
colorlist = ['purple', 'red', 'blue', 'green']

function changeColor() {
  var i = 0
  var interval = null;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i == colorlist.length - 1) clearInterval(interval)
    f(i++)
  }, 2000)
}

function f(x) {
  elem1.style.background = colorlist[x]
  elem2.style.background = colorlist[x]
  elem3.style.background = colorlist[x]
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column3 {
  float: left;
  min-width: 15px;
  max-width: 15px;
  min-height: 15px;
  max-height: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column3" id="1"></div>
  <div class="column3" id="2"></div>
  <div class="column3" id='3'></div>
  <button onclick='changeColor()'> Test </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am wondering how I would do this if I need to call different methods so if there is three functions f1, f2, and f3 where each function does something different example f1(), //wait 2 seconds, f2(), //wait 2 seconds, f3()

Comment: you mean like `changeColor` there can be different functions, that you want to execute?

Comment: please provide a example